# firebase.auth() not working when I try to switch to firestore and added new script tag

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am trying to use firestore and I am for some reason having trouble after I included the

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase-app.js"></script>`
`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebasefirestore.js"></script>`

and deleted my original

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase.js"></script>`

when I check the console log for the problem it says "firebase.auth()" is not a function and I am wondering why

when I switch to the original it works and the firebase realtime database is working but when I switch to the firestore and add the different script tags it states that firebase.auth() is not working

Comment: This is not a library in the Firebase SDK: `firebasefirestore.js`. You're probably looking for `firebase-firestore.js`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 1):

You're including the granular SDKs, which means that only the products whose library you explicitly include. Since you're only include `firebase-app` and `firebase-firestore`, those are the only ones available. If you also want to use Firebase Authentication, incude `firebase-auth` too.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.7/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup